# Save programmatically nested taxonomy term at once

Tags: drupal, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

the code below allows to create taxonomy terms using Drupal API

```
$terms = array(   

      $term1 = array(
      'name' => 'term name', 
      'description' => '', 
      'parent' => array(0), 
      'vid' => $vid,
       ),

      $term2 = array(
      'name' => 'term name', 
      'description' => '', 
      'parent' => array(0), 
      'vid' => $vid,
       ),

      $term3 = array(
      'name' => 'term name', 
      'description' => '', 
      'parent' => array(0), 
      'vid' => $vid,
       ),
);

foreach ($terms as $term) {
$term = (object) $term;
taxonomy_term_save($term);

}
```

It working well for sibling terms but what if I need to create nester taxonomy tree? There is 'parent' key that should contain array of parent term ids to do that

How will I know these IDs before parent terms get saved in DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is added to the passed term object by `taxonomy_term_save` (more specifically by `taxonomy_term_save` calling `drupal_write_record`):

```
$term1 = array(
      'name' => 'term name', 
      'description' => '', 
      'parent' => array(0), 
      'vid' => $vid,
);
$term1 = (object) $term1;
taxonomy_term_save($term1);
echo $term1->tid; // now where did that come from?
```

Comment: ...but you posted the same code. I need to define some ids in 'parent' key (for example 'parent' => array(1, 2, 3)) BUT how could I know those id before they saved to dB? I need to save WHOLE nested taxonomy tree, not save first parent terms than child terms.

Comment: ... but I added a line. That line tells you how to access the key of the term you just created. Use that key to add child terms.

Comment: Exactly this. You can't know the term ID that you'll need to use as a term's parent until you actually save the parent term first.